# There are accounts galore on my xbox and I do not know which is which? need help understand this ecosystem

Tags: xbox, xbox-one

I am a dad of two gamer children (14 and 11). We have a Xbox one and and old Xbox 360. I am extremely confused about the Xbox ecosystem.
The question I have is how can I get information about the account model of XBOX ecosystem.

I have an microsoft email account on xbox.com, it has a gamer tag. However when my kids log in, they have their own gamertags (one each), so a single account has multiple gamertags. There are many other gamertags that I see in the account due to some previous login.

Each of the gamer tags is associated with an email account, that is not necessarily Microsoft account e.g. my daughter has a gamer tag that is using a gmail email account.

I am unable to get a mental model of the whole thing, especially when we bring in the complexity of purchasing, redeeming gift cards and XBox live accounts. The easiest that comes to my mind is that

1. you need an xbox account (Microsoft)
2. you can then add any number of gamertags to it
3. the gamertags however have their own passcodes and email ids

This does not appear to be accurate.

If anyone can help build this mental model for me, either by explaining it or pointing to MS documentation (which I could not find a pointed one explaining this), I would be thankful.

Comment: This is a venue for developers and not end-users, so your question will almost surely get closed as 'off topic'. The ' online profile' is all rooted to a Microsoft Account (MSA), and you can have one gamertag associated with it. You can have additional 'gamer tags' on your Xbox that are NOT online (i.e. don't have an MSA). All digital purchases are associated with MSA-based accounts such as "Xbox LIVE Gold" or "GamePass" memberships. You can designate an Xbox console as your 'home' account for these subscriptions, which any account ON THAT CONSOLE to run your purchased content.

Comment: You can also associate MSA accounts with your MSA account as members of your 'family'. See https://account.microsoft.com/family/about and https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/console/my-home-xbox

Comment: Thanks Chuck, yes probably it is going to be closed. But I have got my answer, thanks again for that.